# How can I completely unbind the default "switch windows" keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts, window-management, gala

I like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (the default shortcut for "Switch Windows") inside a particular program¹.

As a result, I would like to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch windows instead. I've already modified the "Switch Windows" and "Switch Windows backwards" keyboard shortcuts in System Settings:

[image: Switch Windows key bindings]

This causes the new <kbd>Win</kbd> shortcuts to switch windows, but the old <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts still switch windows as well. My goal is to free these shortcuts from the desktop.

Is there a way to completely unbind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> at the OS level?

¹Not that it's terribly important, but I use this key combination to trigger code completion in Emacs. I'm pretty used to it, and would prefer not to change the binding.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as "off topic" as a bug report. If you've changed the shortcut, but Gala is still swallowing the old ones that is a bug. Please refer to https://elementary.io/docs/code/reference#reporting-bugs

Comment: @DanielForé, thanks for the suggestion. I'll head over to Launchpad and report this as a bug. In the mean time, I've found a workaround (see below). I will leave the question and answer up in case they help somebody else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered a workaround via [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/185/2288) to a related question.

First, use `gsettings` to find the internal configuration setting we wish to change:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i switch
# ...
# org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications ['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']
# ...
```

Then, change the individual setting as necessary. In this case:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
```

As suggested by Daniel in the comments above, I have [reported this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492611).