# Is it possible to completely disable Universal Access zoom shortcuts? [Solved]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am able to assign an additional shortcut to zoom in and out using the `System Settings > Keyboard > Universal Access > Magnifier Zoom In/Out` options, but regardless of what I set there, the shortcuts <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> still zoom in and out. 
It's conflicting with a shortcut in another program.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a workaround via [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1818/10244) answer to a related question.

First, use `gsettings` to find the internal configuration setting we wish to change:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i zoom
# ...
# org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings zoom-out ['<Super>minus', '<Super>KP_Subtract']
# org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings zoom-in ['<Super>plus', '<Super>KP_Add']
# ...
```

Then, change the individual setting as necessary. In my case:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings zoom-out "[]"
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings zoom-in "[]"
```

Then you should be able to use the built in elementaryOS settings for the shortcut you want.

It seems like this may be a bug in ElementaryOS. https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/31?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container