# Disable Alt + Space shortcut for window menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

By default, Alt+Space brings up the window menu.

I cannot find it in System Settings -> Keyboard.

I cannot reassign it from there because I want to use it in a text editor in the terminal (nano) to switch between words.

I've tried gsettings after seeing [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-i-reset-keyboard-shortcuts), but I cannot find it there.

Is there a way to disable it, for the terminal at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try;

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep activate-window-menu
```

There should be an entry for *activate-window-menu*.

Remove shortcut;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu []
```

Restore defaults;

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu
```